# NSPredicate always gives back the same data

Tags: objective-c, ios, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I am trying to work with NSPredicates. But it always give me back the same array. Here you can see my predicate.

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"whichAlbum.album_id == %d", AlbumId];
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Picture" inManagedObjectContext:self.genkDatabase.managedObjectContext]];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
```

Also when I try it hardcoded. It gives back the same array.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"whichAlbum.album_id == 5"];
```

My database model is:

[image]

And here you can see how I put data in my database for entity Picture.

```
+ (Picture *)pictureWithGenkInfo:(NSDictionary *)genkInfo
          inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
                     withAlbumId:(int)albumId
                   withPictureId:(int)pictureId;
{

    Picture *picture = nil;

    picture = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Picture"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];
    picture.url                     = [genkInfo objectForKey:PICTURES_URL];
    picture.pic_album_id            = [NSNumber numberWithInt:albumId];
    picture.picture_id              = [NSNumber numberWithInt:pictureId];


    return picture;
}
```

Anybody can help me ?

Kind regards
**EDIT**

```
  for (NSDictionary *genkInfo in albums ) {
        albumId++;
        Album *album = [Album albumWithGenkInfo:genkInfo inManagedObjectContext:document.managedObjectContext withAlbumId:albumId];
        for (NSDictionary *genkInfo2 in pictures ) {
            pictureId++;
            Picture *pic = [Picture pictureWithGenkInfo:genkInfo2 inManagedObjectContext:document.managedObjectContext withAlbumId:albumId withPictureId:pictureId];
            [album addPicturesObject:pic]; // this method should be automatically generated
        }
        pictureId = 0;
        // table will automatically update due to NSFetchedResultsController's observing of the NSMOC
    }
```

Comment: Where are you setting the whichAlbum relationship (or are you adding `Picture`s to the `Album`'s `picture`'s relationship somewhere?)

Comment: @CarlVeazey I've made an edit to my question. You can see how I'm inserting in my database.

Comment: no It always gives back the pictures of the first album

Comment: so, you do `[album addPicturesObject:pic]` but you don't do `pic.whichAlbum = album`, also make sure you save your context after that `[context save:&error]`

Comment: @Ezeki you shouldn't need to explicitly set both ways in a relationship

Comment: @jackslash ok, maybe i shouldn't, but i always do, but another thing is `is context ever being saved???`

Comment: Yes it's saved after inserting into the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better, assuming the value for AlbumId is some kind of number primitive:

```
old style:
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"whichAlbum == %@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:AlbumId]];
modern style: (xcode 4.5)
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"whichAlbum == %@", @(albumId)];
```

As it [looks like](https://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html) `predicateWithFormat:` might only generate proper predicates with `%@` and `@K` in its format strings.

Best: Assuming you have access to the Album managed object you are trying to match try this:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"whichAlbum == %@", album];
```

Match to the object, not one of its properties

Comment: And how do I get "album" then ?

Comment: where does AlbumId come from?

Comment: I give it as a parameter of the function.

Comment: and does the parameter come from an Album object eventually? If so send the Album instance as the parameter instead.

Comment: No it comes from an indexPath.row. Also I tried your code but it keeps  giving me the same pictures every time. It doesn't make sense

Comment: Also when I look at my ID's of moment of creating. I see that there is not the problem. every Album gots it own ID and also every picture

Answer (score 0):

just remove `whichAlbum` and try:

`NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"album_id == %d", AlbumId];`

Comment: Nope, album_id is not an attribute of Picture. So this won't work.

Comment: sorry, according to your model it should be `pic_album_id` not `album_id`. You don't have `whichAlbum` in `Picture` at all.

Comment: pic_album_id is also not working. And whichAlbum is an relation of picture.

Comment: ok i see, so even though you have this in your model you don't fill it with your album data. There must be something like `picture.whichAlbum = album` in order to use `whichAlbum` in predicate, also you have to save the context like this `[context save:&error]` after you made an insert in your `pictureWithGenkInfo ` method, and btw `pic_album_id ` should work even if you didn't set `whichAlbum `